# Laravel: Validate that a field corresponds to a specific row

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-passport

I'm building a registration method for my API using passport. When the user makes his registration, I want to return him the access token, similar when we ask for an access token. For this 'm using grant password clients.

What I've done is to ask in the data of the registration the `client_id` along the `client_secret`.

Then what I'm looking is that my validation rules are able to validate that the `client_secret`, corresponds to the `client_id`.

Here is my registration method:

```
/**
 * Register a new user in the system.
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $vb = User::ValidationBook();
    $data = $request->validate($vb["rules"], $vb["messages"]);

    // Neccesary data to get a token at registration
    $password = $data["user"]["password"];
    $clientId = $data["user"]["client_id"];
    $clientSecret = $data["user"]["client_secret"];

    // If validation passes, create user
    $user = $this->userService->store($data);

    $request->request->add([
        'grant_type'    => 'password',
        'client_id'     => $clientId,
        'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        'username'      => $user->email,
        'password'      => $password,
        'scope'         => null,
    ]);

    // Fire off the internal request.
    $token = Request::create(
        'oauth/token',
        'POST'
    );
    return \Route::dispatch($token);

}
```

And here is the reduces version of my User model, I've all the rules in the validation book method.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * Returns an array that contains two indexes:
     * 'rules' for the validation
     * 'messages' messages given by the validation
     *
     * @return array
     **/
    public static function ValidationBook($except = [], $append = [])
    {
        $book = ['rules' => [], 'messages' => []];
        $book['rules'] = [
            ... the other rules
            //Extra data for register
            'user.client_id' => 'required|exists:oauth_clients,id',
            'user.client_secret' => 'required|exists:oauth_clients,secret'
        ];
        $book['messages'] = [
            ... the other messages
            // Extras
            'user.client_id.required' => 'The client id is required',
            'user.client_secret.required' => 'The client secret is required',
        ];
        if (!empty($except)) {
            $except = array_flip($except);
            $book['rules'] = array_diff_key($book['rules'], $except);
        }
        if (!empty($append)) {
            $book = array_merge_recursive($book, $append);
        }
        return $book;
    }

}
```

How could I add a rule to the `user.client_secret` rule to validate that the secret corresponds to that specific id?
Probably this is not the best option to return the access token after the registration, and If there is a simple way to avoid it I'll be glad to learn about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I am not wrong the validation of the relation between client_id and client_secret is already in place.

Comment: Nope, it does not exists. It is validating that the client_id, and the client_secret are in the database, but not validating that The client with id:3 has a secret of value: ABC123XFY for example. I mean that code will pass the test if the user sends an id of 2, and send the secret of the first client (ABC123XFY)

Comment: You can use a query to check match client_secret & client_id in a Rule class.

Comment: Yeah... Right... Now I remember... You kind of answered your question... Make a model relevant to the table where the client_id and client_secret i stored then use that model to validate the client_id and client_secret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple. On my validation rules, on the `user.client_secret`, I add the following values:

```
$book['rules'] = [
    ... the other rules
    'user.client_id' => 'required|exists:oauth_clients,id',
    'user.client_secret' => 'required|exists:oauth_clients,secret,id,'
];
```

In this, next to the validation of existence of the secret, I add the query to check all the records with a specified id.

Then before the validation I add the desired `id` to the rule:

```
$vb = User::ValidationBook();
$vb["rules"]["user.client_secret"] .= $request->input("user")["client_id"];
$data = $request->validate($vb["rules"], $vb["messages"]);
```